# useLocalStorage hook setState thinks the callback is of type "any". How can I make it recognize the callback type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

useLocalStorage:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(key: string, initialValue: T) {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<T>(() => {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(key)
    return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(storedValue))
  }, [key, storedValue])

  const setValue = (value: T) => {
    setStoredValue(value)
  }

  return [storedValue, setValue] as const
}
```

Note type:

```
export default interface Note {
  createdAt: Date
  title: string
  body: string
}
```

Code:

```
function blankNote(): Note {
  return {
    createdAt: new Date(),
    title: "New Note",
    body: "",
  }
}
  const [currentNote, setCurrentNote] = useLocalStorage(
    "currentNote",
    blankNote()
  )

  function editNote(property: "title" | "body", newValue: string) {
    setCurrentNote(currentNote => ({ ...currentNote, [property]: newValue }))
  }
```

This is the problem line:

```
setCurrentNote(currentNote => ({ ...currentNote, [property]: newValue }))
```

When I hover over `currentNote` I can see that it's of type `Note`, but when I try to access that note within the `setCurrentNote` callback, it's giving me this error:

> Parameter 'currentNote' implicitly has an 'any' type.

shouldn't the type be implied?

Comment: `setCurrentNote` expects `Note` but you pass a function instead. `setValue` should be defined as `value: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>` instead of `value: T`